# file corrupted when downloaded from a swift container

Tags: node.js, openstack, openstack-swift

I want to get a file from a swift container in node.

I'm using this code for making a request (largely inspired by [this code](https://github.com/firejune/swift/blob/master/lib/swift.js)):

```
 var client = https.request(options, function(res) {
    var buffers = [];
    res.body='';

    res.on('data', function(buffer) {
       buffers.push(buffer);

    });

    res.on('end', function(err){
      res.body = buffers.join('');
      callback && callback(res);

    });

  });
```

If download a text file, there's no problem, but for binary data, differences appears between the downloaded file and the original, after some bytes (258 with an mp3 file).

Have you an idea of what could cause a such corruption? character encoding, ending characters which I have to remove,wrong way to merge the datas,...

**update**

I made it work like that:

```
  var client = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.body='';

    res.on('data', function(buffer) {
      res.body+= buffer.toString('binary');
    });

    res.on('end', function(err){
      callback && callback(res);
    });

  });
```

but it's written in the doc that toString('binary') will be deprecated soon, so it's not the best solution.

Comment: what are you doing with res.body in your callback? It's binary data, you should really never be converting it to a String at all. The better solution would be if you could pass a Buffer to the callback, and deal with it properly as pure binary data there. I've added an example to my answer, perhaps it will help

Answer (score 0):

```
  buffers.join('');
```

Does a string join on the array, which is not what you want for binary data. The correct way to concatenate buffers is

```
  Buffer.concat(buffers);
```

See http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength

So you could do this

```
var client = https.request(options, function(res) {
    var buffers=[];

    res.on('data', function(buffer) {
      buffers.push(buffer);
    });

    res.on('end', function(err){
      res.body=Buffer.concat(Buffers);
      callback && callback(res);
    });
});
```

But your callback would have to be expecting a Buffer rather than a String. Of course, being binary data, it shouldn't be a String anyway.